# A way to solve a system of differential equations using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, ode, differential-equations

***The problem:***

I am working on a larger project, part of which is a simulation of the following system in Python.
I have a given system of torsionally vibrating weights, that can be described by a set of equations as

[image]

(*note that there is an error in this picture - the ddot(\phi) terms are supposed to be second derivatives of phi1, phi 2 and phi3, respectively.*)

For the sake of simplicity, let's consider the f term to be equal to for i = {1,2,3}

[image]

**I am looking for a way to numerically solve this set of equations using Python, preferably using the SciPy library for the sake of consistency of tools used in the project.**
*Note: I do not want to resort to actually implementing numerical mathematics but rather use an in-built function like odeint.*

***My shot at the solution:***

I already implemented solution for a simple equation of a damped pendulum
[image]

```
def inversePendulum(angle,t, u, d, regulator):
    w = angle[0]
    phi = angle[1]
    if regulator:
        u = r0*(d-phi)
    dphidt = w
    dwdt = (u - M*g*l*np.sin(phi) - fd * w)/J
    return [dwdt,dphidt]

for i in range(0, N ):
    if i==N-1 or i==N:
        tt = [t[i], t[i]]  # [t1 t2]
    else:
        tt = [t[i], t[i+1]]  # [t1 t2]
    x=odeint(inversePendulum,x0,tt,args=(u[i],d[i],
                                         regulator))
    y[i] = x[1, 1]
    x0 = x[1, :]  # new IC for next integration step
```

So I'm looking to extend this implementation to a 3 DOF system. First, I need to rewrite this set of equations as
[image]

but I am not sure as how to continue.

Is it possible to just extend (and edit the existing equation, of course) the inversePendulum function to contain more variables in an analogous way to my already implemented solution?

Any insight or link to relevant material will help a lot!

Comment: Yes, just extend the existing example. You have to define what ordering of components in the 6 dimensional state vector you use, I'd prefer first all phi, then all omega, so that you can say at the start `phi, omega = state[:3], state[3:]`. Use the `reshape` method of numpy arrays to facilitate array splitting in more general situations.

Comment: Take a look at  sympy https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/pde.html

It might have support for the type you want to solve